# ¿Como agrupo 3 sumatorias en una tabla? MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

Tengo esta consulta de la sumatoria de las tarifas de un gimnasio

```
select sum(tarifa.valor) as total_Mensuales from suscripcion, tarifa where tarifa.id = 'T2' and suscripcion.Id_Tarifa = tarifa.id;
select sum(tarifa.valor) as total_Trimestral from suscripcion, tarifa where tarifa.id = 'T4' and suscripcion.Id_Tarifa = tarifa.id;
select sum(tarifa.valor) as total_Anual from suscripcion, tarifa where tarifa.id = 'T6' and suscripcion.Id_Tarifa = tarifa.id;
```

y los resultado son estos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es que salgan los 3 resultados juntos con una sola consulta, me mencionaron que se puede con un group by pero no se como implementarlo en esto, muchas gracias.

Comment: Comparte información de tus tablas para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar una combinación de `GROUP BY` y `HAVING`:

```
SELECT tarifa.id, sum(tarifa.valor) AS total FROM suscripcion, tarifa
WHERE suscripcion.Id_Tarifa = tarifa.id
GROUP BY tarifa.id
HAVING tarifa.id IN ('T2', 'T4', 'T6');
```